# How to get particular entry with max value from Map in Java Script

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say that I have a Map like:

```
let resultMap = new Map();

Map {
  'Column number: 0 with element: 10' => 3,
  'Column number: 1 with element: 17' => 2,
  'Column number: 2 with element: 19' => 2,
  'Column number: 3 with element: 23' => 3,
  'Column number: 4 with element: 30' => 1
}
```

I want to get an entry with the highest value. In the above example:

```
'Column number: 3 with element: 23' => 3,
```

In Java code I would use code like:

```
Optional<Entry<K, V>> maxEntry = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));
```

but for JavaScript, I can not find out a solution. I have found a partial solution like:

```
let array = Array.from(resultMap, ([number, value]) => ({number, value}));
Math.max(...array.map(o => o.value)));
```

with transforming Map to Array but with above one I will receive value although I need entry with <K, V>. In case that value will be the same for more than one entry we can return each with max value.
I am curious if there is an easier solution. Thanks in advance for help and suggestions.

Comment: You have two entries with value `3`. You want to the last entry or any entry would do?

Comment: @adiga I mentioned it in a comment. It can be the first one every with max value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let recipeMap = new Map([
  ["огурец", 500],
  ["помидор", 350],
  ["лук",    50],
  ["перец", 500]
]);

const result = Array.from(recipeMap).sort(([ ,v1], [ ,v2]) => v2 - v1);
console.log(result[0]);
let i = 1;
while (i < result.length && result[i][1] === result[0][1]) {
   console.log(result[i]);
   i++;
}
```

UPDATE: now all entries with maximum values in output.

Comment: Just `Array.from(recipeMap)` also returns the entries.

Comment: Can we adapt this to return each entry with max value? `'Column number: 3 with element: 23' => 3,` and `'Column number: 0 with element: 10' => 3,`

Comment: ```const result = Array.from(...)...```, print ```result[0]``` and then ```let i = 1; while (result[i][1] === result[0][1]) {console.log(result[i]); i++}```

Comment: @Martin what do you expect the entry to look like? For JS, the key-value pair is just an array with two items - index 0 is the key, index 1 is the value.

Comment: @VLAZ Final collection can be like [entry1, entry2, etc...] but entry <K, V> <'Column number: 0 with element: 10' , 3>

Comment: @Martin `<'Column number: 0 with element: 10' , 3>` should this be an array `['Column number: 0 with element: 10' , 3]`? Or what exactly? In JS there isn't an `Entry` object like in Java. You can have an array with two values (again, that's what normal entries are) or an object with `key` and `value` fields or something similar. But I'm not sure what is the shape of the data you expect.

Comment: @VLAZ, maybe he means not the format of output but the fact that multiple solutions are possible.

Comment: @VLAZ it can be array of objects [{ number: 'Column number: 0 with element: 12', value: 2 }, etc...] is it more clear now? If no I can create JSON for this.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the Map to an array using `Array.from()` or array spread. Reduce the array to the first or the last item with the highest value (just switch the ternary):

```js
const map = new Map([
  ['Column number: 0 with element: 10', 3],
  ['Column number: 1 with element: 17', 2],
  ['Column number: 2 with element: 19', 2],
  ['Column number: 3 with element: 23', 3],
  ['Column number: 4 with element: 30', 1]
]);

const first = Array.from(map)
  .reduce((acc, entry) => entry[1] > acc[1] ? entry : acc, [null, -Infinity]) // the initial value is required to handle empty Maps

const last = Array.from(map)
  .reduce((acc, entry) => acc[1] > entry[1] ? acc : entry, [null, -Infinity]) // the initial value is required to handle empty Maps

console.log({ first, last })
```

To return all entries with the max values, you can use reduce, and store the entries with the max values in an array (`acc`). If a new item has a higher value, replace the `acc`, if it's the same add it, if it's less return the `acc`.

```js
const map = new Map([
  ['Column number: 0 with element: 10', 3],
  ['Column number: 1 with element: 17', 2],
  ['Column number: 2 with element: 19', 2],
  ['Column number: 3 with element: 23', 3],
  ['Column number: 4 with element: 30', 1]
]);

const result = Array.from(map)
  .reduce((acc, entry) => {
    if(entry[1] > acc[0][1]) return [entry]
    
    if(entry[1] === acc[0][1]) return [...acc, entry]
    
    return acc
  }, [[null, -Infinity]])
  
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Can we adapt it to make it return each entry with max value? 'Column number: 3 with element: 23' => 3, and 'Column number: 0 with element: 10' => 3,

Answer (score 1):

## `for..of` loop

### Single item

It's very straight forward using a simple loop. This will run in `O(n)` time and since it's going over the map iterator, it doesn't incur the space penalty of having to materialise extra arrays.

```js
let resultMap = new Map([
  ['Column number: 0 with element: 10', 3],
  ['Column number: 1 with element: 17', 2],
  ['Column number: 2 with element: 19', 2],
  ['Column number: 3 with element: 23', 3],
  ['Column number: 4 with element: 30', 1]
]);

let highest = null;

for(const [key, value] of resultMap) {
  const highestValue = highest?.value ?? -Infinity;
  
  if (value >= highestValue) {
    highest = {key, value};
  }
}

console.log(highest);
```

The [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` provides a null-safe way of getting the value and the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) `??` provides a safe fallback while there is still no highest value found.

### All the highest items

This can very easily be expanded to produce an array with all the highest values by just keeping an array of results and checking the value of the first item. Since they should all have the same value, it will be enough, no need to compare all of them.

```js
let resultMap = new Map([
  ['Column number: 0 with element: 10', 3],
  ['Column number: 1 with element: 17', 2],
  ['Column number: 2 with element: 19', 2],
  ['Column number: 3 with element: 23', 3],
  ['Column number: 4 with element: 30', 1]
]);

let highest = [];

for(const [key, value] of resultMap) {
  const highestValue = highest[0]?.value ?? -Infinity;
  
  if (value > highestValue) {
    highest = [{key, value}];
  } else if (value === highestValue) {
    highest.push({key, value});
  }
}

console.log(highest);
```

## [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

### Single item

In this case, the whole map is materialised into an array but it's still an `O(n)` single iteration that gives you the highest entry.

```js
let resultMap = new Map([
  ['Column number: 0 with element: 10', 3],
  ['Column number: 1 with element: 17', 2],
  ['Column number: 2 with element: 19', 2],
  ['Column number: 3 with element: 23', 3],
  ['Column number: 4 with element: 30', 1]
]);

let highest = [...resultMap].reduce((highest, [key, value]) => {
  const highestValue = highest?.value ?? -Infinity;
  
  if (value >= highestValue) {
    return {key, value};
  }
  
  return highest;
}, null);

console.log(highest);
```

### All the highest items

Again, the same idea as the loop solution above, but using the `.reduce()` method.

```js
let resultMap = new Map([
  ['Column number: 0 with element: 10', 3],
  ['Column number: 1 with element: 17', 2],
  ['Column number: 2 with element: 19', 2],
  ['Column number: 3 with element: 23', 3],
  ['Column number: 4 with element: 30', 1]
]);

let highest = [...resultMap].reduce((highest, [key, value]) => {
  const highestValue = highest[0]?.value ?? -Infinity;
  
  if (value > highestValue) {
    return [{key, value}];
  } else if (value === highestValue) {
    return highest.concat({key, value});
  }
  
  return highest;
}, []);

console.log(highest);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want every entry with a max value, you could keep a `maxValue` variable to keep track of current max value till that entry and update the output array of entries accordingly

```js
let map = new Map([
    ['Column number: 0 with element: 10', 3],
    ['Column number: 1 with element: 17', 2],
    ['Column number: 2 with element: 19', 2],
    ['Column number: 3 with element: 23', 3],
    ['Column number: 4 with element: 30', 1]
  ]),
  maxValue = -Infinity,
  output;

for (const [k, v] of map) {
  if (v > maxValue) {
    output = [ [k, v] ]
    maxValue = v
  } else if (v === maxValue) {
    output.push([k, v])
  }
}

console.log(output)
```